# How to use a php variable inside preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match

```
$pId = "MP000000001648426";
```

Below code is not working. Whats wrong with it?

```
preg_match_all('/<span id="price_$pId".*?>(.*?)\<\/span>/', $product ,$matches);
```

But, when I directly add the string (pId) to preg_match it works.

```
preg_match_all('/<span id="price_MP000000001648426".*?>(.*?)\<\/span>/', $product ,$matches);
```

But I want to provide a variable inside the preg match. How to do it?

Comment: Use double quotes. You can't interpolate variables inside single quoted string literals.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That solved the issue, Post-it as the answer

Comment: This is a dupe of too many questions, no need to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to

```
preg_match_all("/<span id=\"price_$pId\".*?>(.*?)\<\/span>/", $product, $matches);
```

(note that you need real `"` so that PHP Variables are converted)

Alternative solution:

```
preg_match_all('/<span id="price_'. $pId . '".*?>(.*?)\<\/span>/', $product, $matches);
```

Comment: For some reason the alternative solution doesn't work me! I don't like using double quotes for text in PHP, therefore I prefer to concat single quoted text with vars using the dot symbol. But last time I tried this, preg_match literally searched for the single quote character as part of the pattern!!!

This was my code...

`preg_match_all('/[^' . $tron->separator . ']+' . $tron->separator . '[^' . $tron->separator . ']+/u', $tron->getAkas(), $outer);`